# SQL : How do i output date range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can i display a range of date in SQL Server if i have a start date and end date.

Like i have start date  1/1/2014
and end date as 1/30/2014

the output should be

1/1/2014

1/2/2014

....

29/1/2014

30/1/2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CTE u can create dates. A recursive `CTE` is one in which an initial CTE is repeatedly executed to return subsets of data until the complete result set is obtained to know more about `RECURSIVE CTE` **[check here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)**

```
with cte as
(select convert(datetime,'2014-01-01') dates
union all
select dateadd(dd,1,dates) from cte where dates < convert(datetime,'2014-01-30'))
select * from cte
```